# Can I set a Visual Studio 2015 C# application to reopen?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'd like to setup a way to get installed applications to automatically update. The closest I can get to that is to have them poll my server for a "close" flag. If that is is set, the applications MainWindow.xaml.cs closes. This will force the user to open it again, which will pull in the updates (I have the ClickOnce setup to pull updates from a URL)

It would be nicer for the users if I could get the application to open automatically after it closes, is there a way to do that?

Comment: my first thought was to start another application before closing. That other application can start your main application again. And close itself afterwards.

Comment: Why not just restart your own application @Mtihc ?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, if you need to re-install before restarting, doing from the context of the application you're trying to reinstall will be tricky, no?

Comment: No, it is described in the documentation of `Application.Restart()`.

Comment: Ah. Missed the "oneclick" part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [`System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart(v=vs.110).aspx) what you want?

> The most common reason for calling Restart is to start a new version of the application that you have downloaded through ClickOnce using the Update or UpdateAsync method.